# How can I import / export contacts as VCF in Sony Xperia Tipo Dual

Tags: contacts, backup

I'm using a Sony Xperia Tipo Dual with ICS. I need to backup my contacts with or without linked contacts.

Does anyone know the exact procedure to export contacts in VCF format; either directly to PC using [PC companion](http://www.sonymobile.com/in/tools/pc-companion/) or to SD Card using any third party free application?

In addition to that, I want to know if it would be possible to add / update contacts on the mobile through the [Sony PC companion](http://www.sonymobile.com/in/tools/pc-companion/)?

Comment: You can use rocketdial or go contact  ex from play store and they can backup it in vcf format. BTW your default stock app also backup it in vcf format .

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are running Sony's TimeScape Interface. (As you not mentioned anything explicitly) So here are steps:

To back up contacts using a memory card:

1. From the Home screen, tap the Application screens icon.
2. Find and tap Contacts.
3. Press the Menu key, then tap Back up contacts > Memory card > OK.

Tested on Xperia Neo, Xperia Neo V, Xperia Ray running 2.3.4 Gingerbread to 4.0.4 ICS with Sony's TimeScape UI. Should work on Tipo as well.

Here's [a page from Sony's site](http://www.sonymobile.com/us/support/faq/xperia-ray/phone-call-contacts/backup-import-and-send-contacts-ps101/) for further help.

Comment: i cant do that...

while backup it shows error as cant read memory.... :(

Comment: i have connected using the software from

http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/

Comment: @prabhuprabhakaran In that case I think there's some problem while contacts app is trying to read / write data. Do you have an SD card inserted? Have you tried rebooting your phone after this issue? If no, please do so, if yes please show me the screenshot so I can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

On Sony Tipo, go to Contacts. At the bottom there will be three buttons, press the last one that looks like four lines, then go for backup contacts, then back up to SIM, memory card, or internal storage.